# mtpro2 + baskerville in math

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I love the new `Baskervaldx` package, which can be used together with `newtxmath` to get Baskerville-like font in math. However, the Greek letters are awful. I also have the complete `mtpro2` package, which has beautiful Greek letters.

I would like to use those Greek letters with a Baskerville-like font as the italic math font. One crude option would be to use the `mathastext` package but it destroys the spacing in math.

Therefore, I would like to either use `newtxmath` (with the option `Baskervaldx`) with `mtpro2` Greek letters, or `mtpro2` with `Baskervaldx` font for latin letters in math. I think the latter option is more viable than the former (based on what I read and my own trials).

I tried to copy and paste some of the declarations made in newtxmath.sty (in particular the part where they declare the symbol font zbami for math italic) but it doesn't work nicely (there are missing fonts). I tried some other idea reported as a comment below—without success.

Can you give me any suggestion?

---

This is a MWE. This code produces more or less what I want but with ugly consequences to the spacing and also other chars like < or > and |.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
%\usepackage[Baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\noindent $\alpha$ is absolutely integrable iff
\[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\alpha(x)| dx < \infty. \]
\end{document}
```

The ideal solution would not use `mathastext`. So suppose to comment it. Then, if I comment `\usepackage{mtpro2}` and decomment `\usepackage[Baskervaldx]{newtxmath}`, I should add a bunch of commands that allow me to use the Greek letters in `mtpro2`. The other option is to stick to the code above, comment `mathastext` and instruct LaTeX to use `Baskervaldx` as the math font for latin letters.

---

Update:

The question was answered by egreg (see below). If one wants also capital Greek letters from `mtpro2`, I think s/he can append the following code to egreg's one.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"80}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"81}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"83}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"84}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"85}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"87}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"88}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"89}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"7F}
```

Comment: Just to update: I am looking to use some of the ideas in mathastext but just to replace the latin letters. So I am focusing on loading mtpro2, then Baskervaldx, and then do something to replace Times (which is used for latin letters in mtpro2) with Baskervald.

Comment: I also tried to use unicode-math because in that case I could use a command like 
`\setmathfont{texgyreheros-regular.otf}[range=up/{Latin,latin}]`
to set the font for latin letters only, but I do not know the otf for Baskervald (if there is any: it doesn't seem to exist in my texlive folder).

Comment: PleSe, add a minimal example of code.

Comment: I added a MWE. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the lowercase Greek letters, import them from `mtpro2`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[Baskervaldx]{newtxmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP1}{mtt}{\skewchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}{<-7> mt2mif <7-9> mt2mis <9-> mt2mit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}{<-7> mt2bmif <7-9> mt2bmis <9-> mt2bmit}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mtproletters}{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}
% uncomment the following line if you have the full version of mtpro2
%\SetSymbolFont{mtproletters}{bold}{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{"27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varkappa}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{126}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varbeta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{176}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardelta}{\mathalpha}{mtproletters}{178}

\begin{document}

\noindent $\alpha$ is absolutely integrable iff
\[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\alpha(x)| dx < \infty. \]
$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for completeness the same without the added code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So neat. Can I ask you, is it working also for capital Greek letters?

Comment: @MonteCarlo Times letterforms are distinctively different from Baskerville, I wouldn't accept a Gamma that's different from a flipped L. Lowercase Greek is more cursive, so the problem is not the same.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering if the capital Greek letters are still taken by `newtx` or `mtpro2`. It seems to me that they are taken by `newtx`. If I add the following code, it seems that they are taken by `mtpro2` so that all Greek letters are now taken from `mtpro2`. (I will add an answer at the end of my question because it is too long to copy/paste here.) Let me know if you disagree or I am ruining your solution.

Comment: Also, I think that the line to uncomment in the case one has the complete `mtpro2` should be `\SetSymbolFont{mtproletters}{bold}{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}`

Comment: @MonteCarlo Yes, I forgot to fix the name