# How to import few symbols like `\int` and `\sum` from mtpro2?

Tags: fonts, mtpro, newtxmath

In a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419976/mtpro2-baskerville-in-math) it is possible to adopt Greek characters in math mode from `mtrpo2` to be used together with `newtxmath` and `baskervaldx`.

My question is similar, except, I would like to adopt some other symbols like `\int`, `\sum`, or even brackets `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

Instead of completely switching to `mtpro2`, I like to use `newtxmath` as the main math font for the consistency with `baskervaldx` text font, since the text font can be natively used in math.

Is it possible to import the above symbols form `mtpro2` or even from the default computer modern font?

Here are the differences, using `newtxmath`:

[image]

and using `mtpro2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[lf]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Option 1, using newtxmath
\usepackage[baskervaldx,cmintegrals,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath}

% Option 2, using mtpro2 (I only need a few symbols from this package
% \usepackage{etex}
% \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    L^2_0(\Omega) = \left\{ f \in L^2(\Omega)  ~:~ \int_{\Omega} f dx = 0 \right\}.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[lf]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Option 1, using newtxmath
\usepackage[baskervaldx,cmintegrals,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath}

% Option 2, using mtpro2 (I only need a few symbols from this package
% \usepackage{etex}
% \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mtt}{m}{up}{<->mt2exa}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{splgreek}{U}{mtt}{m}{up}
\SetSymbolFont{splgreek}{normal}{U}{mtt}{m}{up}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\splsum}{\mathop}{splgreek}{"50}
\let\sum\splsum
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{splgreek}{"52}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\sum    L^2_0(\Omega) = \left\{ f \in L^2(\Omega)  ~:~ \int_{\Omega} f dx = 0 \right\}.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response, it works perfectly. May I ask to explain above solution? How do you find the codes for each symbol, like `"50` for `int`? For example if I want to do the same for say `\prod` and the brackets `\left\{` and `\right\}` where should I look at?

Comment: Probably just look at the source code of the corresponding package and copy the definition from there.